# How do I find all square images in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files, images, image-manipulation

The images are stored in JPEG and PNG files. I want to get a list of those of them that are square.

Comment: I tried using `file`... then got stuck. Here's a list of all square resolutions `find . | egrep '.jpe?g$' | xargs file -b | egrep -o ', ([0-9]+)x\1'`.
I obviously am not very good at this.

Comment: @nwk, you should post your suggested edit as a new answer, not as an addition to don_cristi's answer.

Comment: @loa_in_: Nice idea to use `file`! I wrote an answer based on it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238949/61562) and credited you for it.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using the command `convert` from ImageMagick and Awk:

```
convert *.png *.jp* -format '%w %h %f\n' info: | awk '$1==$2 { $1=$2=""; print substr($0, 3) }'
```

The command above will output the list of images that have **exactly** the same number of pixels horizontally and vertically. If instead what you want to find is images that only **visually approximate** a square, you can do this:

```
# Find all images in which one side is no more than 5% larger than the other.
convert *.png *.jp* -format '%w %h %f\n' info: | awk '($1>$2?$1:$2)/($1>$2?$2:$1)<=1.05 { $1=$2=""; print substr($0, 3) }'
```

Note that neither command will work correctly if your images' filenames contain newline characters.

Answer (score 4):

Using `exiftool` in the current directory (`.`):

```
exiftool -q -if '$ImageHeight == $ImageWidth' -p '$Filename' -ext jpg .
```

---

Another way to do it with `imagemagick` (via [`fx`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) special operator):

```
for f in ./*.[jJ][pP][gG]
  do
    (( $(identify -format '%[fx:(h == w)]' "$f") )) && printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done
```

The expression `'%[fx:(h == w)]'` returns `1` if `true` and `0` if `false` so, in turn, the return value of `((  ))` will also be `true` and respectively `false`.

---

Both solutions assume input files have `jpg` or `JPG` extension. Adjust per your needs...
Aslo, see *nwk*'s comment below if you're searching files that *look* roughly square.

Comment: If you use `identify -format '%[fx:max(h,w)/min(h,w) <= 1.05]' "$f"` in the loop above you can find files that look roughly square (no side is longer than the other by more than 5%).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on the idea in @loa_in_'s comment. It uses `file`, which for this task is considerably faster than `convert`. It also handles "weird" filenames correctly.

```
file -F '' -0 *.png \
| sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\x00.*PNG.*, \([0-9]\+\) x \([0-9]\+\).*$/\2 \3 \1/;s/^\(.*\)\x00.*JPEG.*, \([0-9]\+\)x\([0-9]\+\).*$/\2 \3 \1/' \
| awk '$1==$2 { $1=$2=""; print substr($0, 3) }'
```

The resolution part of `file`'s output looks different for JPEG and PNG files, so we parse it separately.

Answer (score 1):

An improved version of @nwk to include square png images in any subdirectory:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} convert {} -format '%w %h %f\n' info: | awk '$1==$2 { $1=$2=""; print substr($0, 3) }'
```